# React Router rewriting only not existing url

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hello i want to rewrite only not existing url with react-router-dom. Tha's the code:

```
      <Router>

        <Route exact path={"/"}>
          <Home/>
        </Route>

        <Route exact path={"/login"}>
          login
        </Route>

        <Route path={"*"}>
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Route>

      </Router>
```

Now i want to rewrite only url that not exists, for example "/example", but in this situation Router rewrites "/login" too. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, can you share a `codesandbox` link?

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
<Router>

    <Switch>

        <Route exact path={"/"}>
          <Home/>
        </Route>

        <Route exact path={"/login"}>
          login
        </Route>

        <Route>
         <Redirect to="/" />
        </Route>

    </Switch>

</Router>
```

Comment: No it does not work and does not render the entire app too. Always blank page.